# System verilog constraint for uniform address pattern

Tags: system-verilog

I want to add a constraint on "rand bit [7:0] addr[10]" such that we have address generated in uniformly increasing order from 0th index to 5th and uniformly decreasing order from 6th to last index. I am new to SV constraints, can someone help with ways to do this.

Comment: What is the relationship between 5th and 6th addresses? Are the increasing and decreasing amounts the same value?

Comment: 6th will be one step below 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class A;
  rand bit [7:0] addr[10];
  rand int step; // this needs to be an int to catch underflow/overflow
  constraint uniform {
     foreach (addr[index]) {
        index inside {[0:4]} -> addr[index] + step == addr[index+1];
        index inside {[6:8]} -> addr[index] - step == addr[index+1];
     }
     step inside {[1:25]};
  }
endclass
```